# Power Query's "Load To" trims trailing spaces

Tags: excel, powerquery

I was asked to simplify a pair of Excel workbooks that used Power Query. One of the workbook's power queries used a table in the other workbook as a source. That other table was populated by a power query in the other workbook.

I was asked to eliminate the 2nd workbook. So I examined all the logic in the queries and put all the logic in the queries in the final (and now only) workbook.

It worked fine except that in two of the tables, some of the items now have trailing spaces that were not there before.

I found that the SQL Server that is the ultimate source for all this data DOES have the trailing spaces. And the first power query in the old workbook also has the trailing spaces, even at the very last step.

But the table in that workbook that is loaded by that power query does NOT have the trailing spaces. I tried refreshing the query, and I tried redoing it's "Load To" command to load the table. Still the query **does** have the trailing spaces, while the table it loads does **not** have them.

In the final, single workbook after eliminating that other workbook, queries are also loaded to tables. But those tables retain the trailing spaces from the queries.

Data types are the same between the old and the new. The columns in question have data type "any" (the data type icons show "ABC123").

Although it would be possible to have a macro in the old workbook automatically run when the table is updated, and that macro could be set up to trim trailing spaces, no such macro is in place in that workbook.

I don't see any logic anywhere that looks to me like it would be trimming those trailing spaces. Any idea how that might be happening?

BTW the old system was set up in 2014, so they were probably using Excel 2013 and the Power Query add-in. I'm using Excel 2016 and Get and Transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I see the same trimming from the Data Model.

For the query you've moved, you could check the box to load it to Data Model, and then when it loads to sheet it will come from the Data Model and will have trimmed spaces.

Comment: Wow, that was it! I didn't see where to add it to the data model once it was already loaded, but I copied the M code to a new query and tested checking that checkbox when loading it to a worksheet. Sure enough, no trailing spaces on the worksheet table it loaded to. Seems like a bug that just adding it to the data model would do a trim. Certainly unexpected.

Comment: In an effort to find out whether Microsoft agrees that this is a bug (or if not, why not), and perhaps even fix it, I've posted a support question on answers.microsoft.com. Anyone who sees this and would like to make sure Microsoft knows about this issue and considers fixing it can go to that post and click the button that says you've seen the issue too. Look for the button near the bottom labeled "Me Too". It's at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/excel-2016-data-model-trims-trailing-spaces/29971572-dcf8-4d03-be9d-1db19c364bd0?tm=1494527445193